# How can I create an excel macro that puts data from specific rows into a word file?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have an Excel sheet with monthly fees of hostel, the columns are name, date, month for which paid, amount, status, and some remarks.

I have to provide receipt to each who paid. So how can I automate the task of who paid to provide them a receipt?

Lets say 10 guys I marked paid, then I need to run some macro which will generate receipts for each of them, preferably in a single Word file. Eg: `{name} has paid {amount} for the month of {month} {year} Signature.jpg`

Later I can print the document and cut them and provide to whoever paid.

Comment: So... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am confused how to start. I know basics of excel only.

Comment: Do you need multiple receipts in one document or separate document for each customer? The latter is easier as you can use Word Document Template. Start with creating a template, add bookmarks where information will be added. Form an array with information of paid customers, loop through it and create a Word Document for each customer, modifying bookmarks' text with relevant customer data.

Comment: I need in one document as I want to save pages. The receipt in very small.

Comment: How much receipts will Document hold?

Comment: Maybe 8-10 as it fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to do that.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Add two DocVariables to Word, and run the Macro from Excel, not Word.  If you don't know what a DocVariable is, Google it...